# names of solist are not plotted in hyperframe

Tags: spatstat

- I have a solist of 4 point patterns.
- I then defined
  `names(solist)=c("a","b","c","d")` as a vector of 4 string elements.

Now when I plot just the solist like `plot(solist)`, I get the customized titles on the plot

- I then created a hyperframe as `h=hyperframe(experiments=solist)`

Now when I plot like `plot(h$experiments)` , I have lost the names and the plots now have a default `1,2,3,4` as plot titles.

I do not know if this is how it should be or if I miss something. I would like to retain the names of the solist in the hyperframe so that when I plot the hyperframe, I have the same names as the solist.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hyperframe does not allow the individual entries to have names. There can be row names and column names, but individual entries cannot have names.

If you had done `row.names(h) <- c("a","b","c","d")` then `plot(h$experiments)` would have shown these names as the titles of the plot panels.

PS: Avoid using `solist` as the name of an object. This could conflict with the function `solist()`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that hyper frame is kind of data.fame, so row.names will work. I am sorry, I just meant to say solist_object not solist as name of my object. Thank you for pointing out.